# EVIL AP - Internet connection bridging issue

Tags: linux, man-in-the-middle, kali-linux, iptables

I've been trying to create an EVIL AP scenario in my test lab for a couple of days, but I always face the same issue.

I can connect to the WIFI adapter and I receive an IP address etc, via dhcp.

However the main issue seems to be routing the traffic from wlan0 over to eth0 and out to the internet.

I believe it might be an iptables config issue but im not sure. Here are my current iptable configs:

> iptables --t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
>   iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface at0 -j ACCEPT iptables -t nat -A
>   PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.33:80
>   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

Comment: do you have IP FORWARDING enabled?

Comment: Yeah its enabled
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Comment: If you look at the iptables usage counters, where does the traffic go? Another step is do a pcap on the wlan0 and then on the eth0 to see if its a problem with traffic leaving your AP, or returning.